# I am seeing this error in server.py file, " The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, data-science, data-analysis

Here I am attaching my server.py and util.py

I have trained a model, and now wish to print the data on user's demand.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
#from waitress import serve
import util
import json
#%run util.ipynb

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hi')
def hi():
    return util.areas()


@app.route('/locations')
def locations():
    response = jsonify({
        'locations': util.locations()
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response


@app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_home_price():
    total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
    location = request.form['location']
    size = int(request.form['size'])
    bath = int(request.form['bath'])
    area_type = request.form['area_type']
    balcony = int(request.form['balcony'])

    response = jsonify({
        'estimated_price': util.get_estimated_price(area_type, location, size, total_sqft, bath, balcony)
    })

    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('python flask started')
    app.run()
    #serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=50100, threads=1)
```

util.py

```
import json
import joblib
import numpy as np
__locations = None
__area = None
__model = None


def get_estimated_price(area_type, location, size, total_sqft, bath, balcony):
    x = np.zeros(6)
    x[0] = __area.index(area_type)
    x[1] = __locations.index(location)
    x[2] = size
    x[3] = total_sqft
    x[4] = bath
    x[5] = balcony
    
    return round(__model.predict([x])[0][0],2)
    

def locations():
    return __locations
def areas():
    return __area

def load_saved_artifacts():
    print("loading saved artifacts...start")
    global __data_columns
    global __locations
    global __area
    
    with open('./artifacts/locations.json','r') as f:
        __locations = json.load(f)['data_locations']
    
    with open('./artifacts/area.json','r') as f:
        __area = json.load(f)['data_area']
       
    global __model
    
    __model = joblib.load('./artifacts/Banglore_Real_State_Price')
    print(" loading artifacts is done")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_saved_artifacts()
    #print(locations())
    #print(areas())
    
    print(get_estimated_price('Super built-up  Area','Electronic City Phase II',2,1056,2,1))
    print(get_estimated_price('Built-up  Area','Uttarahalli',3,1440,2,3))
    print(get_estimated_price('Super built-up  Area','Lingadheeranahalli',3,1521,3,1))
    print(get_estimated_price('Super built-up  Area','Kothanur',2,1200,2,1))
```

Immediate help is really appreciated

I have trained a model, and now wish to print the data on user's demand.

I am seeing this error in server.py file, " The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." I checked everything works fine if I am sending data to browser but not when asking for the data, I tried Postman for sending the data.

http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict_home_price -> shows bad request.

http://127.0.0.1:5000/locations -> shows correct data

http://127.0.0.1:5000/hi -> shows correct data

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, when you're sending data to the server it works, and that's because you're using a POST request and the request has form data in it.
But when you're "asking for data", you're probably using a GET request, which has no form data in it, and that's why the server responses with an error.

You can modify your code so you can decide what you should do for each type of request:

```
@app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_home_price():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get form data and do something with it
    elif request.method == "GET":
        # return some value, without looking for form data
```

Comment: What if i use only

@app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

Comment: This is the case in your original question. You must handle GET and POST requests differently, because GET requests don't have any request body. You can still do that in the same function, as I showed in the answer.

Comment: What if I use only -> @app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['POST']) instead of @app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['GET', 'POST']) .

Comment: Then it should work only for POST requests (assuming the request includes the required data in its body), but not for GET requests. That means, for example, that you won't be able to access this route by entering the URL in a web browser.